# No typescript podemos tipar uma variável com um objeto?

Tags: angular, typescript

No typescript podemos tipar uma variável com um objeto? Exemplo: `funcaoExemplo(obj: { [key: string]: any }) {}`

Comment: Vitor, se você tem esse objeto definido, porque não cria uma classe e tipa com a mesma?

Comment: Olá Daniel! Obrigado pela ajuda. Como se faz a tipagem de um objeto com uma classe? Você poderia me dar um exemplo? Att.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Victor,

Abaixo um exemplo bem simples de tipagem de parâmetro e retorno de funções:

```
//Exemplo de classe
class MinhaClasse {
  key: string = "";
}

//Exemplo de função que recebe um parâmetro de tipo específico
function funcaoComParametroTipado(parametro: MinhaClasse) {
  console.log(parametro);
}

//Exempĺo de função que retorna um tipo específico
function funcaoComRetornoTipado(): MinhaClasse {
  let minhaClasse: MinhaClasse;

  minhaClasse = new MinhaClasse();
  minhaClasse.key = "Retorno";

  return minhaClasse;
}

let minhaClasse = new MinhaClasse();

minhaClasse.key = "Parâmetro";

//Chamada com parâmetro tipado
funcaoComParametroTipado(minhaClasse);

//Chamada com retorno tipado
console.log( funcaoComRetornoTipado() );
```

Aqui eu crio a classe MinhaClasse que tem um propriedade chamada key, utilizo essa classe na tipagem de parâmetro e também de retorno.

---

A documentação do typescript é ótims, caso queira dar uma olhada, abaixo o link:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Ajudou bastante!